# Can't send a Magic packet(Wake on LAN Packet) to a created DNS hostname over the Internet

Tags: dns, portforwarding, wake-on-lan, dyndns

I want to wake up my personal computer using "WAKE ON LAN" over the internet i.e by sending a Magic Packet from a remote device.

Following is the configuration

1. **Enabled WOL** in BIOS and the OS as well using guides at [How to Remotely Turn On Your PC Over the Internet](http://www.howtogeek.com/192642/how-to-remotely-turn-on-your-pc-over-the-internet/)
2. Created a hostname **"example.ddns.net"** that maps my changing external IP to a hostname. DNS service is working fine. A Dnslookup of my hostname is successful
3. Port forwarded ports **7 and 9** (Defaults for Magic packet over UDP) to my router's broadcast address
4. My Pc is behind a DLINK 605L router
5. System is either in SLEEP or HIBERNATE state.

When i send a **magic packet locally** i.e from another device connected on the same network the Pc is connected to **Everything goes well**.

as `java WakeOnLan 192.168.0.255 00:0E:62:09:xx:xx`

However when i try sending a magic packet from **another network** specifying the ***MAC address and example.ddns.net*** WOL **doesnt work**

as `java WakeOnLan example.ddns.net 00:0E:62:09:xx:xx`

used the code from here http://www.jibble.org/wake-on-lan/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a basic summary here are things you need to look into:
1. You need to add an entry to ARP table on your router to recognize the incoming WOL request.
2. You need to add a firewall rule to broadcast the incoming magic package on you local lan.
3. You need to find a WOL utility which supports sending magic package to a specific port (this is not needed when within local lan).

For a more comprehensive information please see this reference: http://uneventech.blogspot.com/2012/05/1-turnon-home-pc-remotely-scenario-you.html

Comment: Quite a descriptive link, will try and let you know. thanks for the heads up!